# Flask: refer to 'g' in gevent spawn in a request

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I use db pool in my flask-restful project, I register a `before request` hook so that every request will get a db connection and store in the thread local variable `g`:

```
# acquire db connection from pool
@app.before_request
def get_connection():
    setattr(g, '__con__', MysqlHandler())
```

My module layer will then get the db connection from `g` for CURD:

```
@classmethod
def get(cls, **kwargs):
    res = g.__con__.simple_query(cls.__table__, query_cond=kwargs)
    return cls(**res[0]) if res else None
```

Finally after the request, the connection will be committed and released back to the pool in `after_request` hook:

```
# commit db update after the request, if no exception
@app.after_request
def commit(response):
    if getattr(g, '__con__', None):
        g.__con__.commit()

    return response
```

This framework works fine until I introduce gevent to handle some long term async task in a request:

```
@copy_current_request_context
def my_async_task():
    time.sleep(5)
    print 'I am g', g.__con__

class TeamListView(Resource):
    # http GET handler, return all team members
    def get(self):
        gevent.spawn(my_async_task)
        all_groups = Team.all()
        return return_json(data=all_groups)
```

The above code will return JSON data to front-end immediately, which means the request context will be destroyed after the request, so that the `g.__con__` could not be accessed after 5 seconds sleep in my async task.
My async task has to handle database operation via `g.__con__`, so is there any solution to keep the `g`, event after the request complete ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the error you've got?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I've re-post my question.